# What is a distinct prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

I need to know what a distinct prime is, and what happens when you multiply two of them. How can I figure this out?

Comment: $n$ distinct primes should mean "$n$ different prime numbers"

Comment: If you have two distinct primes than they are each prime and they are not equal to each other. If you multiply them you get a number which has four divisors (including itself) but is not a square or cube

Comment: Commenters kind of beat me to it. That's really all there is to say about them, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pair of distinct prime numbers are primes $p, q$ such that $p \neq q$.

Multiplying two distinct prime numbers $pq$ together gives a composite number whose prime factorization consists only of two primes. This composite number is divisible by $1, p, q, \text{and } pq$.

Nothing particularly fancy about them.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was confused after searching the internet